# How to combine Map values from parent Map with java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream, multimap

I have a map inside a map which looks like this:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>> mapInMap; //--> with values like: 
/*
"a": (1: BigDecimal.ONE),
"b": (2: BigDecimal.TEN),
"c": (1: BigDecimal.ZERO)
*/
```

And I would like to combine the inner maps by expecting the following result:

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> innerMapCombined; //--> with values:
/*
1: BigDecimal.ZERO,
2: BigDecimal.TEN
*/
```

This is my solution with predefining the combined map and using forEach:

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> combined = new HashMap<>();
mapInMap.forEach((str, innerMap) -> {
  innerMap.forEach(combined::putIfAbsent);
});
```

But this will ignore `(1: BigDecimal.ZERO)`.

Could you provide a 1-line solution with java 8 stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your problem is that as soon as you initialize your maps, and add the **duplicate keys** on the inner maps, you will rewrite those keys, since **those maps do not accept duplicated keys.** Therefore, you need to first change this:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>> mapInMap;
```

to a `Map` that **allows duplicated keys**, for instance [Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Google Guava:

```
Map<String, Multimap<Integer, BigDecimal>> mapInMap = new HashMap<>();
```

where the inner maps are created like this:

```
 Multimap<Integer, BigDecimal> x1 = ArrayListMultimap.create();
 x1.put(1, BigDecimal.ONE);
 mapInMap.put("a", x1);
```

*Only* now you can try to solve your problem using Java 8 Streams API. For instance:

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map = multiMap.values()
                                       .stream()
                                       .flatMap(map -> map.entries().stream())
                                       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                                 Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                                 (v1, v2) -> v2));
```

The duplicate keys conflicts are solved using [mergeFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) parameter of the `toMap` method. We explicitly express to take the second value `(v1, v2) -> v2` in case of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

To address why your current solution doesn't work is because `Map#putIfAbsent` method only adds and doesn't replace a value in a map if is already present.

---

**Solution using for-each:**

`Map#put` is a way to go, however its limitation is that you cannot decide whether you want to keep always the first value for such key, calculate a new one or use always the last value. For such reason I recommend to use either a combination of `Map#computeIfPresent` and `Map#putIfAbsent` or better a method that does all that at once which is [`Map#merge(K, V, BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) with a `BiFunction remappingFunction`:

> remappingFunction - the function to recompute a value if present

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map: mapInMap.values()) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, BigDecimal> entry: map.entrySet()) {
         resultMap.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (l, r) -> r);
    }
}
```

---

**Solution using Stream API:**

To rewrite it in the Stream-alike solution, the approach would be identical. The only difference is the declarative syntax of Stream API, however, the idea is very same.

Just flatMap the structure and collect to a map with a [`Collector.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) using `BinaryOperator mergeFunction`  to merge duplicated keys.

> mergeFunction - a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> resultMap = mapInMap.values().stream()
    .flatMap(entries -> entries.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> r));
```

Note: [@dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366871/dreamcrash) also deserves a credit for his good Stream API [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65072057/3764965) in terms of speed.

---

**Result:**

`{1=1, 2=10}` is the result when you pring out such map (note that `BigDecimal` is printed as a number). This output matches your expected output.

```
1=BigDecimal.ZERO
2=BigDecimal.TEN
```

Notice the similarities between [`Map#merge(K, V, BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`Collector.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that use a very similar approach to the same result.